# AES Key Generation

Tags: aes

AES always create a unique key. Even I have my internet disconnected. I know there is very little probability to create same key again that is already generated but my question is that where the algorithm is storing all those keys so that it is making sure that the key is already being used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about [crypto.se] not programming.

Comment: Storing keys is against forward-secrecy. If you really want to store them, store their hashes. This enables comparison...

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm. If you want to store keys to check, you are free to do so.

Keep in mind that "very little probability" is really "incredibly, mind-bogglingly little probability." For a 256-bit key chosen at random, there is a 1 in a million chance that a **single** collision will occur after selecting over 10<sup>35</sup> keys. (That is to say, if you selected 10<sup>35</sup> keys a million times, you would expect **one** of those collections to have a single duplicate.)

To get 10<sup>35</sup> keys, you would need to create about 10,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 keys **per person in the world**. Once you had done that, you'd have a one-in-a-million chance that two keys would collide.

For more details on how you calculate these values, see the [Birthday Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack).

If your random number generator is configured properly, you will never, ever, have a collision on a randomly selected AES-256 key. If you are creating a very large number of keys, say in the tens of billions, I would consider validating how you generate random numbers to verify that it's set up correctly. But for smaller sets, it's incredibly unlikely that's going to be an issue if you're using the normal cryptographic random number generators on common computers and OSes. At very large scales, you're dramatically more likely to have problems due to hardware errors and cosmic rays (yes, seriously) flipping bits than due to random number collisions.

But if you want to check for duplicates, you can keep track any way you like. There is no particular algorithm. Put them in a database and look them up.